# How to create a gh-pages branch in an upstream repo?

Tags: git, github, branch, github-pages

I have forked a project and now I need/want to create a gh-pages branch that will also need to be merged to a gh-pages branch in the upstream project. That branch is not there yet in the upstream repo.
If I create a PR I cannot select to merge it a gh-pages branch in the base/upstream repo.

How can I get a gh-pages branch in an upstream project via my forked repo?

Comment: I think you would need to ask someone in the upstream repository to create the necessary branch first.

Comment: Hi @larsks, thanks for the reply! Can't think of another way either. Will request it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9796370/6309 (2012) and https://stackoverflow.com/q/54396609/6309 (2019) say: "no way" (beside requesting for the target branch to be created first)